# How to delete space between two strings in text?

Tags: javascript, string, concatenation, space

I have a code for example `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab sequi suscipit quibusdam ratione iusto. Qui, vero mollitia! Harum, eos, iste sint reiciendis repudiandae dolorem`. I want to add to this code just 3 three points '...' if I will add it for example like that const a = text + '...' or `${text}${threePoints}` anyway it will be gap,space between last word and 3 points? How to clean this space?

I try all methods who can add string to string

Comment: There is no space at the end of your example string.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab sequi suscipit quibusdam ratione iusto. Qui, vero mollitia! Harum, eos, iste sint reiciendis repudiandae dolorem.";

const threePoints = "...";

const combinedText = `${text.trim()}${threePoints}`;
```

`trim()` method removes any white space from both ends of the `text`